# How to select all and copy from any EditText field outside my app?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, copy, copy-paste

I am making an app which does something like: When I shake the phone it will cut or copy after selecting all text in an Edittext field. I am talking about selecting and copy from any Edit text field outside my app.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: That should not be possible, except via custom firmware or *possibly* by means of an `AccessibilityService`. Copying data from other apps has privacy and security ramifications.

Comment: Is your app providing or act like a keyboard?? Inputs?

Comment: Yess.. correct... i should use accessibility service.... but how should i google? about this thing.... i don't know what to do so i am stuck by that code.... by the way i have made shake detection for triggering that one.... i don't know how to start..